# Rails possible problem with has_many polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

In my application, I have the following models:

**User**

**Psychologist has_many classrooms**

**Teacher has_many classrooms**

**Parent has_many children**

**Director belongs_to school**

**Coordinator belongs_to school**

My user model looks like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord
   has_many :roles

   def has_role? role_name
     self.roles.where(role_type: role_name).any?
   end
end
```

The Role model is polymorphic:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :roleable, polymorphic: true
end
```

And the other models are rollable.

My question is the following, it seems that this is not correct, because some models like: Director, Psychologists, Teachers, Coordinator and Parent. They only have relationships and their database tables do not have any other column except *created_at*, *updated_at*.

Is it okay to only create these models with relationships and have their tables without data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you intend to use **single table inheritance** and not **polymorphic relationships**. If a `Psychologist` is a `User`, it should be the case.

Then you need to add a `type` column of type `VARCHAR` to the users table, and set up your models like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles

  def has_role? role_name
    self.roles.where(role_type: role_name).any?
  end
end

class Psychologist < User
  # no need to set up roles
end

class Teacher < User
  # no need to set up roles
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  # no polymorphic
end
```

The `type` column will be populated with the name of the actual class, like `"Teacher"` etc.

As an instance of `Teacher` is also an instance of `User`, it will have `teacher.has_role?('foo')` and `teacher.roles`, and you will be able to create a role like `Role.create(user: teacher, name: 'bar')`.